# How do I get OracleDB to connect with Express?

Tags: docker, express, node-oracledb

I have installed the oracledb package in express and followed all of the steps in the getting started guide.

I am still getting an error of:

> Error:  Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
>   express_1  | Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
>   express_1  | You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with ldconfig.
>   express_1  | If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
>   express_1  | http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

Is this suggesting I need to install the oracle client library in express?

I am using a docker container for my Angular/Express setup and am unsure how to do this. I attempted to set up the PATH/ENV on my local windows PC but as you would imagine that has had no effect.

Currently my only call to OracleDB is the first step in this tutorial: https://www.techiediaries.com/node-oracle-database-crud/

Answer (score 0):

Follow the node-oracledb [installation instructions](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html) and install Instant Client on your computer / container.    This is done independently of Express or Node.js.   There is a section there on installing inside Docker.  Docker is discussed in further detail in [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1).

Also check out [Creating a REST API with Node.js and Oracle Database](https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm providing you a sample code where you need to download instant client directory and keep it in main folder. Also provide the user name, passowrd and connectString. Code will work for node 14, 16, 18.

```
const express = require("express");
const oracledb = require("oracledb");

const app = express();

// Download instantclient and kept in main directory.
try {
  oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: './instantclient_19_8'});
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Whoops!');
  console.error(err);
}

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  oracledb.getConnection({
    user: "abc",
    password: "def",
    connectString: "IP:PORT/ServiceName"
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log({ scode: 200, msg: `Connected to DB` });
      // logger.error({ scode: 200, msg: `Connected to DB` });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log({ scode: 500, msg: `DB Connection Error: ${error}` });
      // logger.error({ scode: 500, msg: `DB Connection Error: ${error}` 
  });
  next();
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening to port ${port}`);
});
```